Line through $A$ parallel to $\alpha$ and incident on $r$.
I tried to solve point $(1.)$ of this exercise, but it seems that no such line exists. 
I would be very happy if someone could check my work, because it seems strange to me that there isn't a solution. 
A thousand thanks!
Given in space an orthogonal monometric reference, consider the line $r$ represented by:$$
r: \begin{cases}
x+y = 0 \\
z = 0
\end{cases}
$$the point $A(1,1,1)$ and the plane represented by
$$\alpha : x + y + z + 1 = 0$$Represent:
$(1.)$ The line through $A$ parallel to $\alpha$ and incident to $r$.

The vector of the direction of $r$ is orthogonal to the normal vector of $\alpha$,
if $r$ is parallel to $\alpha$.
So if the line is parallel to the plane, then they are orthogonal.

$\text{First step}:$ I would find the plane parallel to $\alpha$ and passing through $A$ and i know that the line i am searching is in this plane, then find the intersection of the found plane with $r$ and finally i can find the line.
A plane parallel to $\alpha$ will have a normal vector that will be the same as $\alpha$, but multiplied by an arbitrary parameter $k$. If $\vec{n}_{\alpha} = \langle 1, 1, 1 \rangle$, then the normal vectors of the parallel planes will be of the form $k\langle 1, 1, 1 \rangle$.
$\text{Second step}:$ Now i need to search the plane that passes through $A$ and paralle to $\alpha$. 
I can use the fact that the plane has the same normal vector as $\alpha$.
The generic equation of a plane in space is of the form: 
$ax + by + cz + d = 0$ 
Since the plane i am looking for passes through the point $A(1, 1, 1)$ and has the same normal vector as $\alpha$, i will have 
$x + y + z + d = 0$ 
Substituting the coordinates of $A$ into the plane equation: 
$1 + 1 + 1 + d = 0 \Rightarrow d = -3$ 
Thus, the equation of the plane passing through $A$ is parallel to $\alpha$ is $x + y + z - 3 = 0$
$\text{Third step}:$ Now, i know that the line i'm searching lies on this plane, i need to find the intersection of this plane with the straight line $r$.
Substituting $z = 0$ into the plane equation, I get: 
$x + y + 0 - 3 = 0$ 
$x + y = 3$ 
$\begin{cases} x + y = 3 \\ x + y = 0 \end{cases}$
this system is impossible, the two lines do not intersect.
So $r$ is parallel to $\alpha$.
Some checks i did: 
$r$ is parallel to $\alpha$? 
the scalar product is zero, the two vectors are orthogonal. 
$x = t$ 
$y = -t$ 
$z = 0$ 
so $r$ is $\langle 1, -1, 0 \rangle$ 
$\langle 1, -1, 0 \rangle \cdot \langle 1, 1, 1 \rangle = 0$ and $(1,1,1)\notin r$
So if $s$ is parallel to $\alpha$, it can't intersect $r$, unless $r$ and $s$ are on the same plane, but not in this case, where $s$ is the line i am searching.

Indeed, there is no solution.
I follow your proof until equation
$$x+y+z=3\tag{1}$$
Afterwards, I would re-write it a little differently as follows.
(1) means that any line passing through $A$ and parallel to the plane can be represented by this kind of pair of equations :
$$\begin{cases}x+y+z&=&3\\
ax+by+cz&=&d \end{cases}$$
for certain constants $a,b,c,d$.
Now, let us express that there exists a point of intersection $(x,y,z)$ between this line and line defined by $x+y=0$ and $z=0$.
It means that extended system :
$$\begin{cases}x+y+z&=&3\\
ax+by+cz&=&d\\
x+y&=&0\\
z&=&0 \end{cases}$$
has a solution, which is impossible due (more or less as you write it) to the fact that summing eq. 3 and eq. 4 contradicts eq. 1.
